# Altium how to remove 'ghost' ActiveBoM manufacturer link

Tags: components, altium, bom

While creating manufacturer links for a part in `ActiveBoM` I added the wrong part to the entry.

Normally it's straight forward to remove either with right click or from the `Create/Edit Manufacturer Links` menu. However one DigiKey link always remains and I can't remove the entry. It also doesn't appear in the `Create/Edit Manufacturer Links` menu.

[image]

I've tried adding the manufacturer link again which places an entry in `Create/Edit Manufacturer Links` menu but after removing the unwanted entry the ghost one still shows up.

Removing the part and placing it again doesn't solve it either. Is Altium linking to the entry on another level which isn't obvious?

Comment: This might be more of a software question. It's possible that you found a bug in the software. I believe you should direct this question to Altium and probably report this.

Answer (score 2):

Got it - The card was pinned to the BoM entry. Unpinned it (top left corner), added the unwanted Part Number again and then removed the entire entry from `Create/Edit Manufacturer Links` menu.